# Как создать нового пользователя при вводе в инпут с помощью конструктора JS

Tags: javascript, html, localhost

Есть пара инпутов - например login & pass и кнопка, нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку эти данные отправились в localhost, и при повторном нажатии, если значения инпутов другие, они заняли следующие две ячейки в lh. Если значения те же то ничего не должно поменяться.
**ОГРОМНАЯ ПРОСЬБА!!!** просто подтолкнуть к решению, примерно рассказать/показать как это должно осуществляться, нужен ли тут конструктор вообще и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

по сути вам нужно считывать данные с инпутов допустим методом post, посылать их в обработчик, который перешлет их в bd, там(в bd) должна быть создана таблица, которая запишет в себя введенные данные, потом из этой таблицы вы выводите данные на страницу, предварительно установив проверку, условие, есть ли введенные данные в таблице, если такие данные уже есть, то не нужно выводить, а написать допустим, что они уже есть в bd.

А лучше посмотрите [вот этот видео урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvgOPJQA8Zk) или [серию уроков по php](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6xtQQqx1tg)

и уже потом делать, это с учетом, что вы знаете разметку html

пример похожий на то, что вам нужно, естественно без подключения к bd

```js
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'music');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        prinf("Соединение не установлено", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

    if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['username'])) //Если есть данные
    {
      $user=$_POST['name'];
      $username=$_POST['username'];
      // Записываем их в переменную $text
      $query = "INSERT INTO forever VALUES(null, '$user', '$username')";
        $mysqli->query($query);

        echo "данные отправлены <a href='player.php'> назад </a>";
    }
    else // Если данные не переданы
    {
      echo "Данные не переданы!"; //Выводим сообщение об ошибке
    }
```

```css
body{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column-reverse;
            }
            table{
                margin: 20px auto;
            }
            td{
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid blue;
            }
            div{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
            div > input{
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                padding: 3px;
            }
```

```html
<table>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Название</td>
                <td>Автор</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                ?>
        
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['autor']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            
            <?php } ?>

            <form action="handle.php" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Название">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Автор">
                    <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
                </div>
            </form>
        </tbody>
    
  </table>
```